# Looking for the limit of $\frac{e^z-1}{z(z-1)^2}$ as z goes to zero

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I can't figure out why

$$
\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{e^z-1}{z(z-1)^2}=1
$$

Could someone please go through each step for me please?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{z}=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+....$$. Hence $$\frac{e^z-1}{z}=1+\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{z^2}{3!}+...$$.

So $$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{e^z-1}{z(z-1)^2}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1+\frac{z}{2!}+..}{(z-1)^2}=1$$

Comment: thanks very much. i thought this might be the way but i got a little confused regarding the series. But now i understand

Answer (score 5):

Spotting that there's a derivative hidden in there makes it very easy to compute:
$$\lim_{z \to 0} \dfrac{e^z-1}{z(z-1)^2} = \lim_{z \to 0} \left( \dfrac{e^z-e^0}{z-0} \cdot \dfrac{1}{(z-1)^2} \right) =  \dfrac{d}{dz}(e^z) \bigg|_{z=0} \cdot \dfrac{1}{(0-1)^2} = 1$$
This uses the fact that
$$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

Answer (score 3):

L'Hopital's rule:
$$
\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{e^z-1}{z(z-1)^2}= \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{e^z}{(z-1)^2 + 2z(z-1)} = \frac{e^0}{(-1)^2} = 1
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
The simplest is to use the power serie of exp but I don't if you know it :
$$\exp(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k!}$$